# CSS Solution to custom order collapse of elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a set of div elements that need to collapse in a specific way and I'm not sure how to do it. Here is what it looks like un-collapsed:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------
```

And collapsed:

```
---------
|   2   |
---------
| 1 | 3 |
---------
| 4 | 5 |
---------
|   6   |
---------
```

Note that element 2 stays at the top and goes full-width.

So I need a non-flexbox and non-JS solution to this problem due to institutional requirements of the client (browser support issues, etc..).

The bottom part is easy, but I can't figure out some sort of float situation or otherwise to make element 2 stay at the top and have it's surrounding elements collapse below it. I know I could pull element 2 out of the collection of elements and absolute position it in a parent and overlay it into the grid when un-collapsed, but the positioning in solutions like that is always a little wonky in one browser or the other, and looks a little off.

JS isn't completely out of the question, but I really don't want to, as there is a lot of other JS related to this feature I'm developing and I don't want to add complexity there. I will accept flexbox answers as I may be able to convince the client that it is the only way to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: use css position: absolute, left, top styling to second div, to make it out of flow.

Comment: you *can't* detect *wrapping* of elements in CSS... for a flexbox solution too, you'll have to use *media queries* to target both layouts...

Comment: @kukkuz I'm not detecting, this will all be based on media queries.

Comment: @ganeshphirke I suppose that works, but it requires setting predetermined height offsets on the in-flow elements which is kinda messy, as element 2's height may change dynamically based on CMS output, but I know there may be no easy solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using a *wrapping flexbox* that uses [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to get the desired layout. Note the use of `order: -1` to bring the second element to the top. The rest is fiddling around with *width*.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
  order: -1;
}

.wrapper div:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
    order: initial;
  }
  .wrapper>div {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm gonna give it a half hour, but I think I'm going to select this answer. I grepped the applications CSS assets, and it looks like the client already does use flexbox in some active CSS modules, so I think I can get away with this.